# find minimum and maximum values based on dates using Pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a set of dates and I am trying to find a way to get minimum and maximum values:

```
My Data is:
    organizationId    UpdatedAt
    "984d"    2021-03-23T20:43:52.579+00:00
    "984d"    2021-03-23T10:43:52.579+00:00
    ....
```

I need the max and min value only for updated column.

Here I want a result like UpdatedAt.Max - UpdatedAt.Min in days.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['UpdatedAt'].agg(['min','max'])` and then you can subtract the corresponding columns.

Comment: not working getting some error '<=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'"

Comment: You might want to review your actually data. There is no indicator of `dict` in your sample data.

Comment: Updated the question and when I do  df.groupby('organizationId')['updatedAt'].agg(['min','max']) I am getting '<=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: Still no sign of `dict` in your sample data. You need to manually check if they are there and what you want to do with them... For example `for i,r in df.iterrows(): if isinstance(row['UpdatedAt'], dict): print(i)`...

Comment: Using     for i,r in df.iterrows(): 
        if isinstance(df['UpdatedAt'], dict): print(i) no result

Comment: not `df['UpdateAt']` but `row['UpdateAt']` :-)

Comment: "row" is not defined

Comment: I mean `r`, as in `for i, r`...

Comment: I am getting nothing

Comment: @QuangHoang my updatedAt value is like {'$date': 1616573566159} so how do I convert all the values to datetime.